# Typescript dynamic imports typing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, dynamic-import

In typescript when I have a dynamic import, which I get dynamically for example:

```
getImport().then((result: any) => { // do stuff  });
```

Where getImport function gets a dynamic import Promise e.g.

```
import(`../guideContent/Typescript/basics/introduction/introduction`)
```

I also know that all of these dynamic imports give back the same type e.g.

```
Interface Example {}
```

How do I type result (in example any type) properly?

I have tried `result: typeof ContentItems`, and `result: ContentItems` but this didn't work

Comment: What happens with the attempts you've tried? On another tangent, does `getImport` accept a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)?

Comment: `.then((result: any) =>` is wrong. That's awful code

Comment: @AluanHaddad I know that why I am trying to type it :p

Comment: @AluanHaddad: I'm sure `.then((result: any) => {})` is just the example here because OP doesn't know how to type it as `Example`.

Comment: Use inference. The return type of `getImport` should not be specified nor should the parameter type of `result`

Comment: @Wing that is the case

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen: ok great. It may be as simple as `getImport<ContentItems>().then()`, assuming the type authors have typed it nicely. See [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4F8BQ+MAriAmMOiMgOYRgCSAtgA7pRgA8AKgHwAUAShz5kY5FHrEo1EBADuyAApR0TYAGcIPAUOQBeXjlyCA3PgL46jVuy4Z0AwQDowACwgh+-SRuIAbMGFDYzMgA) in the TS Playground.

Comment: @Wing your suggestion is not type safe it's just another way of writing a type assertion and should be avoided as it doesn't solve the problem and increases obscurity

Comment: Yes that's true, I was operating off the assumption TS was unable to infer because OP is trying to manually type something. So let's take a step back: OP if you don't explicitly type anything is TS able to infer the type?

Comment: That's correct. It is possible to write the type explicitly but it's extremely cumbersome in this situation and should not be done for a variety of reasons including maintainability